# How to get the index from 2 different lists which matches values from 3rd list

Tags: c#, linq, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below code will check if testingvalues are available in Element or Element2 List. But how can i also get the index for it when it matches ?

```
public void Method3(List<string> testingValues, IList<IWebElement> Element, IList<IWebElement> Element2)
{
  if (testingValues.All(item => Element.Any(x => x.Text == item) || Element2.Any(y => y.Text == item)))
    {

    }

    else
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a helper-method that uses IList.IndexOf:

```
private int[] GetIndices(string key, IList<IWebElement> objectList) {
  return objectList.Where(e => e.Text.Equals(key)).Select(e => objectList.IndexOf(e)).ToArray();
}


public void Method3(List<string> testingValues, IList<IWebElement> Element, IList<IWebElement> Element2) {
    if (testingValues.All(item => Element.Any(x => x.Text == item) || Element2.Any(y => y.Text == item))) {
        foreach(string key in testingValues) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Indices of {0} in first list: {1}", key, IndicesString(GetIndices(key, Element)));
            Debug.WriteLine("Indices of {0} in second list: {1}", key, IndicesString(GetIndices(key, Element2));
        }
    } else {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

}

private string IndicesString(int[] indices) {
    if (indices.Length == 0) return "NONE";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("{");
    for(int i=0; i<indices.Length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(indices[i]);
    }
    sb.Append("}");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: how can i co related with above ?

Comment: I don't known what you wan to do with the indices. If you call it inside your test method it will return a list containing the indices of all matched elements. I'll try to improve my answert If you tell me what you want to do with the index.

Comment: ok testingvalues will contains 3 values and List 1 ( Element will contains 30 values ) and List2 (Element2 will contains 20 values ) now when All testing values will try to match with ELement list or Element 2 list and when they match i need the index for them. So i can print it  in the console output.